# Azure AD B2C - ASP.NET Core SignUp Link

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I have an ASP.NET Core Web App and a Azure AD B2C tenant.

In the view I can make button entries in the following style and everything is working:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a></li>
     <li><a asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="EditProfile">Edit Profile</a></li>
     <li><a asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ResetPassword">Reset Password</a></li>
     <li><a asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a></li>
</ul>
```

And in the web app `appsettings.json` this is configured:

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "[...]",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "[...]",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpOrSignInPolicy",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordResetPolicy",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEditPolicy"
  }
```

I want to add a button entry for direct access to the sign up page of the `SignUpOrSignInPolicy` but this is not working:

```
<li><a asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignUp">Sign up</a></li>
```

What do I have to change? Or is there any documentation about this "AzureADB2C Account" controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom Account Controller to present user with Sign-up link on the login page and to route to respective action.  Check below code for reference -

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult SignUp()
    {
        return this.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, "B2C_1_B2C_POC_SignUp");
    }
}
```

Also, modify the StartUp.cs Services by adding the authentication service for Signup Policy like below :-

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureADB2C", options));
            services.AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddOpenIdConnect("B2C_1_B2C_POC_SignUp", GetOpenIdSignUpOptions("B2C_1_B2C_POC_SignUp"))
                 .AddCookie();
```

Here, is the Method for adding OpenId SignUp Options referenced in the above code -

```
private Action<OpenIdConnectOptions> GetOpenIdSignUpOptions(string policy)
            => options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress =
                   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/abc.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=" + policy;
                options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxx";//this.ClientId;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout/" + policy;
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/";
            };
```

Comment: I did not get that.  I see your code referring to "Account" Controller using asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignUp".
You solution should be containing "Controllers" folder having "AccountController.cs" file. This file will have "AccountController" class with all Action methods. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-2.1 to get more details on controllers.

Comment: No it comes from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI` I think.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you are using inbuilt Nuget package for AzureADB2C Policies. I also do not see if only SignUpPolicy is inbuilt into Nuget package.  However, I have achieved the same by creating a custom Account Controller.  I have updated my response with the details.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I am not able to make this work with Microsoft.Identity.Web, see my Q here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67593086/azure-adb2c-net-core-5-web-app-how-to-access-specific-signup-userflow-from-r